# algorithm to find the dd/mm format of a year day?

Tags: c#, algorithm, date

Am looking for a algorithm that finds the ***dd/mm*** format of a given year number
(1 - 365)

**Example :**

**1 --> 01/01**

**364 --> 30/12**

Comment: `(new DateTime(year,1,1)).AddDays(number-1).Day` and the same for `.Month` should do (if you need the format in a string `.ToString("dd/MM")` will do too)

Comment: Is the assumption always the current year?

Comment: This sounds like a fun school project

Comment: @CarstenKönig Why you are not adding this as answer? I was adding this as an answer, but then I saw your comment :)

Comment: k - why not - done - thx

Comment: @vcsjones - "... for a given year ..."

Comment: @HenkHolterman - " ... for a given year number (1-365)". I don't think the year itself is known.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Didn't say that when I commented; looked like it was edited within 5 minutes of being posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Carsten has mentioned, you can use the BCL utilities to do this quite easily. If you really are looking for an algorithm to do this (perhaps for learning), you can do it like so:

```
static void DayAndMonth(int number, bool leap, out int day, out int month)
{
    var monthLengths = new int[] { 31, leap ? 29 : 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    day = number;
    month = 1;            

    while(day > monthLengths[month - 1])
    {
        day -= monthLengths[month++ - 1];
    }
}
```

This can be used like so:

```
int day;
int month;
DayAndMonth(365, true, out day, out month); // 30, 12
```

Comment: In truth, this was my first idea, but after that I thought - what the hell, why not all the way then with 365 elements?

Answer (score 7):

try

```
var date = (new DateTime(year,1,1)).AddDays(number-1);
var yourDay = date.Day;
var yourMonth = date.Month;
```

if you need the format in a string just add

```
var yourFormat = date.ToString("dd/MM");
```

I think this should do the trick